# python package structure and global variables

Tags: python, module, package, structure

I created a package in python. In the **init** file I placed a variable that must be available in all the modules of this package.

Example:

```
# main script    
from _Framework.STB import DB
DB.environment = 'lab'
channel = DB.Channels.ChannelStatic.getChannelByNumber(416)
...

# Channels.py module in the package
from _Framework.DB.__init__ import cursor
from _Framework.DB.__init__ import environment
from time import *
...
```

The problem is that everdy call to

```
from _Framework.DB.__init__ import xy
```

overwrites my "global" variables

How can I solve?

Thanks

EDIT:

init.py:

```
all = [ 'Events', 'Channels', 'Genres', 'Subgenres','EPGSections'] 
try: 
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,db) 
    cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
except: 
    cursor = None 
    environment = 'live'
```

I import the DB package and I set the "environment" variable, but when the Channels module is imported, I think, it makes a new call to init.py and reexecutes its code so "environment" is overwritten. I'm looking for a clean way to share a variable between modules of the same package

Comment: I don't really understand the problem from you question. Can you post the __init__.py code and some more code from the module where the import "overwrites your 'global' variables" stating what exactly is overwritten and by whom?

Comment: ######################## __init__.py

__all__ = [ 'Events', 'Channels', 'Genres', 'Subgenres','EPGSections']

try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,db)
    cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    
except:
    cursor = None

environment = 'live'

In my_script.py I import the DB package and I set the "environment" variable, but when the Channels module is imported, I think, it makes a new call to __init__.py and reexecutes its code so "environment" is overwritten.

I'm looking for a clean way to share a variable between modules of the same package

Comment: You know you can edit the question right ?

Comment: Please see my response on why it was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure but if I understand correctly. YOu should just use the edit on your question and post correctly formatted code:

```
__init__.py:

all = [ 'Events', 'Channels', 'Genres', 'Subgenres','EPGSections']
try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,db)
    cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
except:
    cursor = None
    environment = 'live
```

Now in Channels.py you want to change `_Framework.DB.__init__.cursor` and `_Framework.DB.__init__.environment` and this changes should be seen all around your program?

If this is what you want you should know that when you do in a import:

```
 from _Framework.DB.__init__ import cursor
 from _Framework.DB.__init__ import environment
```

What happens is that you get two variables cursor and environment in your Channels.py module namespace and any change you do will only be visible in that module. If you want to achieve your result try this:

```
import _Framework.DB

_Framework.DB.cursor = new_cursor
_Framework.DB.environment = new_environment
```

This way you actually change the module variables. Now in the rest of your program, when you want to see the changes took effect you could either:

1. Acces the varibles in the same way you changed them:

   import _Framework.DB

   ```
   _Framework.DB.cursor        #changes made in other module will have effect
   _Framework.DB.environment   #changes made in other module will have effect
   ```
2. import like you did, BUT make sure the changes you want are done BEFORE you do any imports.

   As an negative example for the second case:

   ```
   #module Vars
   a = 1

   --------------------------

   #module Do_change
   import Vars
   Vars.a = 2

   --------------------------

   #module A
   from Vars import a


   --------------------------

   #module B
   from Vars import a

   --------------------------

   #some random module
   import A
   import Do_change
   import B
   ```

Now if you are in this order of imports when you import A it will create a variable a in A's namespace with the value of Vars.a. The Do_change will edit the variable accordingly, but A will have no knowledge of this. B however who is imported after will see the correct Vars.a = 2.

That's why I really reccomend the first option as it is the correct approach in my opinion.

Comment: thank you man for the answer, I'm sorry for my bad formatted answer but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to answer a question before 8 hours have passed after posting it. Anyway I solved by creating another module Setup and move all the code from __init__ inside of it. It works now. I will try to implement you solution and se if it works better. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

Importing from module `__init__` like

```
from package.__init__ import X
```

runs the module code every time. That's why your variable gets overwritten. This is because the `__init__` module is getting added twice(with different names) in `sys.modules`. First, as  your package's name when it is importing it then as `package.__init__` while importing it explicitly. As the source is loaded twice, the code is executed twice.

However you don't need to do it like this, you only need to do:

```
from _Framework.DB import cursor
from _Framework.DB import environment
```

Then your code would only run once.

Comment: +1 Indeed, importing from a package's `__init__` is a poor python programming practice.